# JavaScript no es Java, pero ¿por qué el nombre?

Tags: java, javascript

Muchos como yo alguna vez pensamos que había una relación entre Java y Javascript.

Javascript no es Java.

> JavaScript no crea applets ni aplicaciones independientes. En su forma
>   más habitual, JavaScript está en documentos HTML y puede proporcionar
>   niveles de interactividad en las páginas web que no se pueden
>   conseguir con HTML simple.
>
> Diferencias clave entre Java y JavaScript
>
> •Java es un lenguaje de programación OOP, mientras que Java Script es
>   un lenguaje de scripts OOP.
>
> •Java crea aplicaciones que se ejecutan en una máquina o explorador
>   virtual, mientras que el código JavaScript sólo se ejecuta en un
>   explorador.
>
> •El código Java necesita compilación, mientras que el código
>   JavaScript está en todo el texto.
>
> •Necesitan diferentes plugins.

Fuente: https://www.java.com/es/download/faq/java_javascript.xml

> JavaScript se diseñó con una sintaxis similar a C, aunque adopta nombres y convenciones del lenguaje de programación Java. Sin embargo, Java y JavaScript tienen semánticas y propósitos diferentes.

Fuente: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript

Por qué comparten "Java" en el nombre? Viene de un origen en común o están basados en lo mismo? Por qué se llaman parecido?

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51273/discussion-on-question-by-woody-javascript-no-es-java-pero-por-que-el-nombre).

Comment: Para quienes votan en contra y piensan X, les comento que como comunidad en algún momento aceptamos tener este tipo de preguntas. Revisar [aquí](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/165/227).

Comment: Java, según tengo entendido es por el rinoceronte de Java, y Java es un lugar geográfico.

Comment: La búsqueda/investigación sobre el tema ha sido muy superflua.

Comment: @Rubén diría que "el resultado de la búsqueda" fue superfluo, pero no la búsqueda, y no te recomendaría juzgar ciegamente acerca del esfuerzo de otro antes de preguntar. Como se ve en mi respuesta a esta pregunta, estoy dando un hecho importante que no fue comentado por nadie más. No veo cómo tu comentario podría ser constructivo para esta pregunta. Y creo que no soy el único que se hizo esta pregunta alguna vez. Criticar es muy fácil con el diario de hoy, pero no puedo aceptar una crítica tan irreal de alguien que no se ha interiorizado en el tema.

Comment: [Anuncio del lanzamiento de Javascript](http://web.archive.org/web/20070916144913/http://wp.netscape.com/newsref/pr/newsrelease67.html) en 1995. Es interesante el contexto histórico  en la respuesta a tu pregunta y cómo las cosas han evolucionado despúes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Citando la misma fuente de [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Nacimiento_de_JavaScript)

> Nacimiento de JavaScript
>
> JavaScript fue desarrollado originalmente por Brendan Eich de Netscape
>   con el nombre de Mocha, el cual fue renombrado posteriormente a
>   LiveScript, para finalmente quedar como JavaScript. El cambio de
>   nombre coincidió aproximadamente con el momento en que Netscape agregó
>   compatibilidad con la tecnología Java en su navegador web Netscape
>   Navigator en la versión 2.002 en diciembre de 1995. La denominación
>   produjo confusión, dando la impresión de que el lenguaje es una
>   prolongación de Java, y se ha caracterizado por muchos como una
>   estrategia de mercadotecnia de Netscape para obtener prestigio e
>   innovar en el ámbito de los nuevos lenguajes de programación web.8 9
>
> «JAVASCRIPT» es una marca registrada de Oracle Corporation.10 Es usada
>   con licencia por los productos creados por Netscape Communications y
>   entidades actuales como la Fundación Mozilla.11 12
>
> Microsoft dio como nombre a su dialecto de JavaScript «JScript», para
>   evitar problemas relacionadas con la marca. JScript fue adoptado en la
>   versión 3.0 de Internet Explorer, liberado en agosto de 1996, e
>   incluyó compatibilidad con el Efecto 2000 con las funciones de fecha,
>   una diferencia de los que se basaban en ese momento. Los dialectos
>   pueden parecer tan similares que los términos «JavaScript» y «JScript»
>   a menudo se utilizan indistintamente, pero la especificación de
>   JScript es incompatible con la de ECMA en muchos aspectos.
>
> Para evitar estas incompatibilidades, el World Wide Web Consortium
>   diseñó el estándar Document Object Model (DOM, o Modelo de Objetos del
>   Documento en español), que incorporan Konqueror, las versiones 6 de
>   Internet Explorer y Netscape Navigator, Opera la versión 7, Mozilla
>   Application Suite y Mozilla Firefox desde su primera versión.[cita
>   requerida]
>
> En 1997 los autores propusieron13 JavaScript para que fuera adoptado
>   como estándar de la European Computer Manufacturers 'Association ECMA,
>   que a pesar de su nombre no es europeo sino internacional, con sede en
>   Ginebra. En junio de 1997 fue adoptado como un estándar ECMA, con el
>   nombre de ECMAScript. Poco después también como un estándar ISO.

Comment: No me percaté que ahí estaba. Entonces, es solo un nombre mal empleado?

Comment: Aparentemente así es, por lo que entiendo, al salir al mismo tiempo pensaron que era de la misma familia y se hizo común el nombre

Comment: Gracias. Me aclaraste una duda que tenía hace mucho

Comment: A mi me dijo un pajarito que paso de llamarse *MOCHA* a llamarse *JavaScript* porque el nombre era mas comercial :/

Answer (score 2):

A partir de la respuesta de Ezequiel ezzekl Canul, pude encontrar más información, particularmente este articulo: http://www.infoworld.com/article/2653798/application-development/javascript-creator-ponders-past--future.html; en el que Brendan Eich, el creador de JavaScript dice:

> No tiene nada que ver con Java...
>
> A principios de diciembre (1995), Netscape y Sun hicieron un acuerdo de licencias, y se convirtió en JavaScript. Y la idea era convertirlo en un lenguaje de scripting complementario, que vaya con Java, con el lenguaje compilado.

Answer (score 2):

Pues básicamente por aspectos mercadológicos, para tener una mayor aceptación cuando surgió, pues Java era la moda.

> Además, justo antes del lanzamiento, Netscape decidió cambiar el nombre por el de JavaScript. La razón del cambio de nombre fue exclusivamente por marketing, ya que Java era la palabra de moda en el mundo informático y de Internet de la época.
>
> Fuente:
>   http://librosweb.es/libro/javascript/capitulo_1/breve_historia.html